# Vim syntax file - quote at the end of function name [dg programming language]

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to write a syntax file for the dg programming language. It's not very complex, and it's derived from Python, so I copied from the Python syntax file.

The problem is that function names can have a single quote at the end:

```
a = list' 1 2 3  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Obviously from the quote onwards, the line is highlighted as a string.
The string definition, which I have taken from the Python syntax file, is this:

```
syn region dgString start=+[bB]\='+ skip=+\\\\\|\\'\|\\$+ excludenl end=+'+ end=+$+ keepend contains=dgEscape,dgEscapeError
syn region dgString start=+[bB]\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"\|\\$+ excludenl end=+"+ end=+$+ keepend contains=dgEscape,dgEscapeError
syn region dgString start=+[bB]\="""+ end=+"""+ keepend contains=dgEscape,dgEscapeError
syn region dgString start=+[bB]\='''+ end=+'''+ keepend contains=dgEscape,dgEscapeError

syn match  dgEscape +\\[abfnrtv'"\\]+ display contained
syn match  dgEscape "\\\o\o\=\o\=" display contained
syn match  dgEscapeError "\\\o\{,2}[89]" display contained
syn match  dgEscape "\\x\x\{2}" display contained
syn match  dgEscapeError "\\x\x\=\X" display contained
syn match  dgEscape "\\$"
```

I'd like to have the quote at the end of function names not highlighted (normal text). How can I accomplish this?

For reference:

- dg lang home page: http://pyos.github.io/dg/
- dg tutorial: http://pyos.github.io/dg/tutorial

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that function names can contain a quote character?  How do I know that `rb'` is the start of a raw, binary string and not a function name?  I think the important thing is to make sure that the single quote is part of the syntax element that describes the function name; then you will not have to modify the definition of a string.

Comment: Well actually it doesn't say it. But if you do a quick search through the tutorial you can see that `tuple'`, `list'` and `dict'` are used. I also tried to define a function with a quote in the repl and it works.  As for your second question, it can be verified that `rb'` is not a valid function name (and neither `b'` or `r'`), while  others combinations (such as `rib' = -> 2`) are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default python syntax highlighting, it looks as though `list` is part of the `pythonBuiltin` syntax group.  (See the example under `:help synID()` for how to check.)  So I tried

```
:syn keyword pythonBuiltin issubclass iter len list locals map max nextgroup=pythonFoo
:syn match pythonFoo /'/ contained
```

and then your sample text

```
a = list' 1 2 3  # [1, 2, 3]
b = list 'a' 'b' 'c'
```

is highlighted correctly:  `list'` is recognized as a Builtin followed by a Foo, and `'a'` is recognized as a String.

The idea is that my newly created syntax item is given priority after vim has finished processing one of the listed keywords, so the `'` is gobbled up by the new group and is not available as the start of a string.

In principle, you can do the same thing with user-defined functions.  The problem is coming up with a syntax definition that just matches functions.  The default python syntax file seems to highlight function definitions but not usage.  (More precisely, a function name preceded by `def` or `class` or `@`.)

Another approach is to modify the definition of a string by inserting a zero-width start-of-word atom before the optional `[bB]` or similar character, or insisting that the string not be preceded by a word character.  Dealing with just the single-quote version of a string (the first line of your example) that would be

```
:syn region dgString start=+\%(\w\@<!\|\<[bB]\)'+ skip=+\\\\\|\\'\|\\$+ excludenl end=+'+ end=+$+ keepend contains=dgEscape,dgEscapeError
```